# Concentration on number of blue balls among n balls uniformly sampled among b blue and g green balls?

Tags: expected-value, random

I am looking to prove a tight concentration on the expected number of blue-colored balls in a sample of $n$ balls chosen randomly from a pool of $b$ blue balls and $g$ green balls.

Namely, after sampling $n$ balls **without replacement** from a collection of $b$ blue balls and $g$ green balls, prove that the number of blue balls in the sample is tightly concentrated around the expected value $\frac{nb}{(b+g)}$. In other words, if $X$ is the number of blue balls in the sample find an upper bound on:

$$P(|X-E(X)| \geq \epsilon) \leq ???$$

I thought about using Chernoff bounds but that can't be done since the sampling is done **without replacement**. Any other way of doing it?

Comment: Based on other recent posts, I think you are looking for Azuma-Hoeffding

Answer (score 0):

b Blue and g Green balls are mixed. From this collection probability of picking a particular ball is $1/(b+g)$ and probability of picking a blue ball = probability of picking $b$ particular balls.

So probability of picking a blue ball from the collection = $b/(b+g)$

Similarly, proabbilty of picking a green ball = $g/(b+g)$

The n balls are picked at random. When you pick something at random, the probability of something being present among the picked items = probability of it being picked

Probable number of blue balls = (Total number of balls) x (Probability of picking a blue ball)

= $(n) (b/(b+g))$

= $nb/(b+g)$

Assumptions :

1. n is less than (b+g)
2. $nb/(b+g)$ is an integer

But assumption 2 can be relaxed if we are allowed to round off the answer

Comment: Thank you! But I was actually more concerned with finding a tight concentration around the expected value, whose calculation is quite elementary. I edited the question to reflect that.